# Access the DOM element from controllerAs directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.3.15 and have a directive that uses `controllerAs` and `bindToController=true`.  I would like to access the directive's DOM element so that I can do `element.bind('someEvent', myHandler)`.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that was easy.  You can inject `$element` into the controller function to have access to the DOM element.